# Rearrange an array by an array of indexes - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of `$Percentages1` that I have ordered in descending order using `arsort()` and then I have taken an array containing the new key order using `array_keys()` called `$keyorder`

My question is how do I now rearrange another array `$Percentages2` into the same key order as `$Percentages1`?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks very much!

Edit - Code as requested:

```
//$Percentages1 before sort for example =
// Array ( [0] => 5.10 [1] => 1.52 [2] => 8.42 [3] => 1.11 [4] => 1.35 )
arsort($Percentages1);
//$Percentages1 after sort =
// Array ( [2] => 8.42 [0] => 5.10 [1] => 1.52 [4] => 1.35 [3] => 1.11 )
$keyorder = array();
//So $keyorder is =
// Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => 4 [4] => 3 )
$keyorder = array_keys($Percentages1);

//Now I want to do something here to rearrange a $Percentages2 array
//in the same index order as $keyorder.
//For example from this
// Array ( [0] => 2.50 [1] => 3.52 [2] => 9.42 [3] => 9.81 [4] => 0.35 )
//To...
// Array ( [2] => 9.42 [0] => 2.50 [1] => 3.52 [4] => 0.35 [3] => 9.81 )
```

Comment: did you tried using [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) function?

Comment: @mend3 ksort() sorts by key - the input array is already sorted by key, and needs to be sorted into the same order as values in another array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not adverse to creating another array variable, the simplest course here is just to loop over `$keyorder` and append the elements at the corresponding key from `$Percentages2` onto a new array;.

```
// Sorted as you already have it...
$keyorder = array_keys($Percentages1);
// Final array
$output = array();
foreach ($keyorder as $key) {
  $output[$key] = $Percentages2[$key];
}

// Don't need the source anymore
unset($Percentages2);
```

Their key order as appended onto `$output` will be retained in the final result.

Given your input arrays, this produces

```
print_r($output);
Array
(
    [2] => 9.42
    [0] => 2.5
    [1] => 3.52
    [4] => 0.35
    [3] => 9.81
)
```

You actually don't need to use `array_keys()`. Following the call to `arsort()`, you can `foreach` over the sorted `$Percentages1` and sort to `$output` by key:

```
// Skip array_keys, and read the sorted array directly
arsort($Percentages1);
foreach ($Percentages1 as $key => $value) {
  // Same as before inside the loop
  $output[$key] = $Percentages2[$key];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this would work perfectly. I am just curious if there is an alternative way to tackle it, regardless, thanks for a quick and working answer that I can use!

Comment: For starters, you can skip `array_keys()` as I just added.  If I think of a way using native `array_*()` functions I'll post it, but honestly I would just use a loop.

Comment: Just saw your edit - Ah I see! That is neat, thanks very much!